# DVD drive: disks are not visible to Windows

Tags: windows, drivers, dvd

I have an issue with my DVD drive. Every time I insert a CD, either Windows thinks there's no CD while there is, or it shows no files as if the CD is empty.

Other programs, such as IsoBuster, show the contents correctly.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/TxE5St6.png]

And here's the screenshot of the drive device properties, in case it's helpful:

[image]

Comment: buy another drive and see what happens, first step of cd rom troubleshooting. 95% of the time a malfunctioning drive.

Comment: @Sickest thank you for the tip. I'm not going to do that, as I use CDs quite rarely, and it's not a critical issue for me. It's just inconvenience. But doesn't the fact that it's visible in IsoBuster, but not in explorer, mean that it's an issue with explorer/Windows?

Comment: does this happen with all discs? also that looks like a music disc, if its a store bought cd, they normally encrypt the cd, not allowing you to see the data. try a cd with actual data on it.

Comment: Yes, it happens with all disks. What you see on the screenshot is a manually burned data disk, with mp3 files of some audio records of mine.